# customized chapter 'number'

Tags: sectioning, chapters

Admit, this is a very special question, but I am quite sure, that it is
realizable with LaTeX.

I would like not to count my chapters like

1 foo

1.1 Problems

1.2 Solutions

2 bar

2.1 Problems

2.2 Solutions

but

LAW foo

LAW.1 Problems

LAW.2 Solutions

VNR bar

VNR.1 Problems

VNR.2 Solutions

and so on.

Any ideas?

Remark: I do not need an index, a TOC would be nice (only on the highest level) but is not crucial.

```
\document{book}
\begin{document}
 \chapter{foo}
 \section{Problems}
 \section{Solutions}
 \chapter{bar}
 \section{Problems}
 \section{Solutions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `article` does not have `\chapter` ;-)

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes! I am going to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterkey}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\chapter@key}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\chapter@key}{???} % initialize
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\chapter@key}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapterkey{LAW}
\chapter{foo}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}

\chapterkey{VNR}
\chapter{bar}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa Separation of tasks.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot. And the main advantage is really that it is more flexible as I do not have to define the prefix in advance. I modified the command to \newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{\chapterkey{#1}\chapter{#2}}.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\ifcase...\fi` conditional in advance (requires the relevant chapter prefixes to be defined in advance, of course too!)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{20pt}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{20pt}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{%
  \ifcase\value{chapter}
  \or
  LAW%
  \or
  VNR%
  \or
  FOO%
  \or
  FOOBAR%
  \or
  UPVOTEANSWERS%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}

\chapter{bar}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}


\chapter{more foo}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}

\chapter{Even more foo}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

A more flexible version with `expl3` features: Storing all in a list and grab the n-th item:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_juergen_chapternumbers_seq 

\newcommand{\StoreChapterNumbers}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_juergen_chapternumbers_seq {#1}%
}

\newcommand{\grabchapternumber}[1]{%
  \seq_item:Nn \l_juergen_chapternumbers_seq{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\StoreChapterNumbers{LAW,A-TEAM,BAR,WHO,UN}

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{20pt}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{20pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{%
  \grabchapternumber{\number\value{chapter}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}

\chapter{bar}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}


\chapter{more foo}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}

\chapter{Even more foo}

\section{Problems}
\section{Solutions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly (not regarding the error, that my beamer class is too old). However I do not understand the code of the ExplSyntax, alas. So I prefer the simpler solution with \ifcase.

Comment: @Jürgen: `beamer`????

Comment: Yes, beamer. I got an error message saying something about a required beamer version. But when I try to replicate this dubious message does not show anymore. It must have been a relic, perhaps in an old aux-file or something like this.

Comment: @Jürgen: Hm, does `beamer` have chapter sectioning???

Comment: Don't know, probably not. I have a test bench to test small snippets of code (in the sense of a minimal working example) and there may be old aux-files in this directory with the same name. This is my only idea how this message might have happened.

Comment: @Jürgen: Well, I wondered about using my (or egreg's) code in beamer document at all